# Why Doesn't Setting Jackson to Accept Empty Lists as Null Work?

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services, jackson

My company has a Java web service using Spring Web that accepts JSON via a REST API. We're using Maven and our Jackson version is 2.9. We're trying to prevent deserialization exceptions from being thrown when an integrator passes in an empty list when our API isn't expecting one.

For example, here's my application class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@EnableWebMvc
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Student.java class:

```
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.Map;

@Data
public class Student {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Map<String, String> classGrades;
}
```

A StudentController:

```
package com.example.example.controllers;

import com.example.example.models.Student;
import org.springframework.http.RequestEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

@RestController()
@RequestMapping(value = "/Students/", produces = "application/json")
public class StudentController {

    @PostMapping(path = "")
    public RequestEntity<Student> createNewStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {

       return null;
    }
}
```

The application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.accept-empty-array-as-null-object=true
```

The pom.xml contains all the default dependencies, with the following added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Every other project file is default to the project structure generated by the Spring initializer. The expected request body (JSON formed using Postman):

```
{
  "firstName": "Mark",
  "lastName": "Twain",
  "classGrades": {

  }
}
```

Works just fine. However, if any field (though in our specific case, the `classGrades` field) receives an empty list, a Jackson deserialization exception is thrown. An example JSON request that fails:

```
{
  "firstName": "Mark",
  "lastName": "Twain",
  "classGrades": []
}
```

And the exception that is thrown:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 65, column: 28]
```

According to the project's [github](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features) page, the option ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT should resolve this issue for us. We've tried setting this directly on an `ObjectMapper` configuration object and within `application.properties` using the line:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.accept-empty-array-as-null-object=true
```

Neither method seemed to take effect. We're currently using a workaround using the `@JsonDeserialize(using = MyCustomDeserializer.class)` annotaion on fields prone to this problem. However, we would like to be able to have all of our fields treat empty lists as null by default.

Are we misunderstanding the configuration option and using it incorrectly? Is there a way to treat empty lists as null within our app, and if so, how can we accomplish this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `ObjectMapper` directly, nor with a simple Spring Boot app. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I will work to provide this, though it will take some time.

Comment: *FYI:* `JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY` only affects serialization (writing JSON), not deserialization (reading JSON).

Comment: @Savior Sorry to keep you waiting. I've updated the question with what I think is a reprex. I'm still new to asking questions, so let me know if you need more.

Comment: Is there anything else you're not showing us? I can't reproduce this, even after adding lombok. Are you maybe declaring a different `ObjectMapper` bean?

Comment: @Savior I forgot I had added the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation to my application class to mimic my company's application as closely as possible. I just tried removing that and it worked! I don't have much experience with Spring. Do you have an idea of why that would cause issues with the empty array flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this example case, my problem was the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation within the `ExampleApplication` class. Removing that annotation allowed me to successfully send an empty array to my endpoint, which then received it as a null object.

**Note**

My original problem still exists within my company's application, even after removing the annotation. However, it seems like this may be an issue with a different setting that might be clashing with `...accept-empty-arrays-as-null-object`.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, and the same solution of removing `@EnableWebMvc` solved the problem. Not sure why, nor what the value was of the annotation - however it seems everything else still works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

A Map is serialized as

```
{ "k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}
```

An empty Map is serialized as

```
{ }
```

In your example you try to put a [], which represents an empty list or array, into a Map and that is why Jackson complains. Simply, cannot map an empty list into a Map.
This also explains why enabling ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT has no effect

### Update

I was not right. Jackson can map empty array to a Map.
Created a minimal springboot example that uses the **spring.jackson.deserialization.accept-empty-array-as-null-object=true** property and can map an empty array [] to the Map

Check [here](https://github.com/routis/jackson-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/routis/examples/jacksondemo/JacksonDemoApplicationTests.java) if you want.

Comment: This is the entire purpose of that `DeserializationFeature`. From the document they linked: _Determines whether empty Array value ("[ ]" in JSON) is accepted as null value for regular POJOs ("beans") with data-binding: this can be useful when dealing endpoints written in a language like PHP that has loose typing and may represent missing objects as empty Arrays._

Comment: @savior I think you are wrong. Please note that the bean in the example uses a Map<String,String>, while the JSON uses an array/list. They don't map. The Jackson error is very clear on this.

Comment: Just look at the test from the source code: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/d2c083a6220f2875c97c29f4823d9818972511dc/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/struct/EmptyArrayAsNullTest.java.